# Find number of different lines between SVN revisions

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

How to find the number of lines which are different between two SVN commits?

Like modified, commented added etc.

Is there any direct command to do this?

Say for example version 1 has 500 lines and  version 2 has 650 lines. Then the output would be like: `Difference: 150`

Comment: So, if you've removed 20 lines in r100 and 17 lines in r200 you want `-3`? And the same for added and modified? I'm pretty sure there isn't a builtin command for that. I'm not even sure that Subversion has the concept of "modified" line.

Comment: If you add 10 lines and remove 10 lines, do you want a result of 0 or 20 ?

Comment: @blue bird:added:10, deleted:10

Comment: Not possible without some serious `grep`ping

Comment: To what end? If you describe the problem you're attempting to solve/question you're trying to answer, instead of what you *think* is the route to the solution, you may get a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

diffstat does what you want:

```
svn diff -r[oldrev]:[newrev] | diffstat
```

Example:

```
 $ svn diff | diffstat
 some_file.py |   17 ++---------------
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 15 deletions(-)
```